# Print Zero Even Odd problem of leetcode shows error Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried the following code for leetcode problem of Print Zero Even Odd problem. 
It is showing me Time Limit Exceeded error while testing for simplest input. 
Can anybody give some suggestions? 
https://leetcode.com/problems/print-zero-even-odd

```
class ZeroEvenOdd {

    private int n;

    public ZeroEvenOdd(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    // printNumber.accept(x) outputs "x", where x is an integer.
    boolean z = true;
    public void zero(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if(z) {
                printNumber.accept(0);
            }
            z = false;
            odd = !odd;
            try { notifyAll(); } catch(Exception e){}
            do { try { wait(); } catch(Exception e){ } } while(!z);
        }
    }
    boolean odd = false;
    public void even(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            do { try { wait(); } catch(Exception e){ } } while(z || odd);
            if(!odd && !z && i%2 == 0) {
                printNumber.accept(i);
            }
            z = true;
            try { notifyAll(); } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

    public void odd(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            do { try { wait(); } catch(Exception e){ } } while(z || !odd);
            if(odd && !z && i%2 == 1) {
                printNumber.accept(i);
            }
            z = true;
            try { notifyAll(); } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `synchronized`: the code will looks more simple

```
class ZeroEvenOdd {
    private int n;

    public ZeroEvenOdd(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    private enum STATUS{
        ZERO, ODD, EVEN;
    }

    private STATUS status = STATUS.ZERO;
    private int x = 0;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    // printNumber.accept(x) outputs "x", where x is an integer.
    public void zero(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        while(x<=n){
            switch(status){
                case ZERO:
                    synchronized(lock){
                        if(x < n){
                            printNumber.accept(0);    
                        }
                        if(x%2==0){
                            status = STATUS.ODD;
                        }else{
                            status = STATUS.EVEN;
                        }
                        x++;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void even(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        while(x<=n){
            switch(status){
                case EVEN:
                    if (x<=n){
                        printNumber.accept(x);
                    }
                    status = STATUS.ZERO;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void odd(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {

        while(x<=n){
            switch(status){
                case ODD:
                    synchronized(lock){
                        if(x <= n){
                            printNumber.accept(x);
                        }
                        status = STATUS.ZERO;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For a complete reference of `synchronized`, visit [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)